# Как получить текущую высоту прокрутки?

Tags: javascript, html, css, прокрутка

**window.pageYOffset** и **window.scrollY**, возвращают 0, скорее всего из-за **overflow: hidden**, но его **убрать** я **не могу** т.к. использую **locomotive scroll**, может есть способ получить текущую прокрутку относительно элемента, или кто-то работал c **locomotive scroll** и знает как с помощью него получить высоту прокрутки.

На всякий случай вот документация: https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll

Answer (score 0):

```
const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll();
scroll.on('scroll', (args) => {
  console.log(args);
});
```

Внизу документации, перед зависимостями, описано.